# Health Check and Monitoring of Web services in a Java web application

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, jetty, spring-boot-actuator

I need to monitor and later generate reports about the time taken, number of times the service was hit, etc. This should be dynamic in nature.

My Java web application is based on Jetty embedded server which has REST and Soap based services. I want to monitor each request, the number of times the service was called, the time taken by the service etc. My requirement is similar to what Spring Boot Actuator does. But I do not want to move my application from embedded Jetty to Spring Boot.

Kindly suggest a simple and effective way to meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Add filter to read every request and save the same to database or in Elasticsearch for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Install [javamelody](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#javamelody-setup) for your webapp. Or with the [javamelody spring boot starter](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter) in Spring boot if you change your mind.

It will monitor http requests, including REST and SOAP requests, with for each different request: hits, mean and max response time for day, week, month or year periods.
And it will do even more with a less than 10 minutes install.

Disclaimer: I have created javamelody.